# Probability density function nonuniformly sampling between two theta angles?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dirac-delta

I'm looking for a PDF that nonuniformly samples orientations between two theta angles, let us say [pi/2 - pi/6, pi/2 + pi/6], whereby theta refers to the theta angle ranging between 0 and pi in the classical spherical coordinate system. So far I used a shifted Dirac PDF to sample only the pi/2 orientation, but I now need some sort of "truncated ellipse- or Gaussian-like" PDF, fulfilling the usual normalization condition, to be able to nonuniformly sample a range of theta angles. Anyone out there who knows of a PDF with these properties? That would really help! Cheers

Comment: You can use a triangle PDF between those points.

Comment: @sudeep5221: thank you. There are actually a number of PDFs available, which have support in the bounded interval [0,1]. I think the truncated normal PDF might be a better option. Do you know of any "wrapped versions" of PDFs with support on [0,1], perhaps something like the raised cosine PDF, but wrapped on the unit circle?